# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl with no grid lines

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

how can I create a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl with no grid line separators? I'm using MFC in Visual C++.

Comment: Are you talking about horizontal lines?

Comment: I've never tried to do this, but, if I were, I'd take a look at writing my own [OnDrawList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983123.aspx) event handler.  Looking at the actual code, it shows some line drawing.